# SSRS Total Time in HHMMSS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-2012

[image]

From the image above, I am totalling the column HHMMSS is SSRS with the below expression:

```
    =CStr(sum(CInt(split(Fields!HHMMSS.Value,":")(0)))
     +sum(CInt(split(Fields!HHMMSS.Value,":")(1)))\60)
       &":"& CStr(sum(CInt(split(Fields!HHMMSS.Value,":")(1)))
      mod 60+sum(CInt(split(Fields!HHMMSS.Value,":")(2)))\60) 
      &":"& CStr(sum(CInt(split(Fields!HHMMSS.Value,":")(2))) mod 60)
```

It works well if there is no blank in the column but gives an error when there is no value or a blank. How do I overcome this?
The query for the report is:

```
    DECLARE @Table TABLE 
    (
          RowID       INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
 , EmpID       INT NOT NULL
 , StartTime   DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT('1900/00/00')
 , FinishTime  DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT('1900/00/00')
 , JobID       INT NULL
 , IdleTime    INT 
    )

    INSERT INTO @Table(EmpID,StartTime,FinishTime,JobID,IdleTime)
    VALUES (100,'2011-09-08 09:00:03.410','2011-09-08 09:55:18.153',12,1)
         , (100,'2011-09-08 11:55:03.810','2011-09-08 12:30:18.153',12,-1)
         , (101,'2012-10-17 09:19:52.637','2012-10-17 17:19:52.637',15,1)
     , (101,'2012-10-17 12:30:52.637','2012-10-17 13:25:52.637',15,-1)
     , (103,'2012-10-17 09:00:03.410','2012-10-17 16:19:52.637',20,1)
     , (103,'2012-10-17 13:00:03.410','2012-10-17 13:49:52.637',20,-1)
     , (104,'2012-10-17 09:00:03.410','2012-10-17 15:19:52.637',54,1)
     , (104,'2012-10-17 11:00:03.410','2012-10-17 13:19:52.637',54,-1)
     , (105,'2012-10-16 09:00:03.410','2012-10-17 18:19:52.637',56,1)
     , (105,'2012-10-17 13:00:03.410','2012-10-17 14:19:52.637',56,-1)
     , (106,'2012-10-10 09:00:03.310','2012-10-17 15:19:52.637',10,1)
     , (106,'2012-10-17 10:00:03.410','2012-10-17 10:34:52.637',10,-1)
     , (106,'2012-10-17 13:00:03.410','2012-10-17 13:35:52.637',10,-1)
     , (107,'2012-10-17 09:00:03.410','2012-10-17 15:19:52.637',17,1)
     , (108,'2012-10-17 09:00:03.410','2012-10-17 15:19:52.637',19,1)
     , (109,'2012-10-17 09:00:03.410','2012-10-17 18:19:52.637',11,1)
     , (109,'2012-10-17 10:00:03.410','2012-10-17 10:19:52.637',11,-1)
     , (109,'2012-10-17 12:00:03.410','2012-10-17 12:20:52.637',11,-1)
     , (109,'2012-10-18 14:00:03.410','2012-10-18 14:20:08.677',11,-1)
     , (110,'2012-10-17 09:00:03.410','2012-10-17 15:19:52.637',20,1)
         , (101,'2012-10-18 09:19:52.637','2012-10-18 17:19:52.637',15,1)
     , (101,'2012-10-18 12:30:52.637','2012-10-18 13:25:52.637',15,-1)
     , (103,'2012-10-18 09:00:03.410','2012-10-18 16:19:52.637',20,1)
     , (103,'2012-10-18 13:00:03.410','2012-10-18 13:49:52.637',20,-1)
     , (104,'2012-10-18 09:00:03.410','2012-10-18 15:19:52.637',54,1)
     , (104,'2012-10-18 11:00:03.410','2012-10-18 13:19:52.637',54,-1)
     , (105,'2012-10-18 09:00:03.410','2012-10-18 18:19:52.637',56,1)
     , (105,'2012-10-18 13:00:03.410','2012-10-18 14:19:52.637',56,-1)
     , (106,'2012-10-18 09:00:03.310','2012-10-18 15:19:52.637',100,1)
     , (106,'2012-10-18 10:00:03.410','2012-10-18 10:34:52.637',100,-1)
     , (106,'2012-10-18 13:00:03.410','2012-10-18 13:35:52.637',10,-1)
     , (107,'2012-10-18 09:00:03.410','2012-10-18 15:19:52.637',17,1)
     , (108,'2012-10-18 09:00:03.410','2012-10-18 15:19:52.637',19,1)
     , (109,'2012-10-18 09:00:03.410','2012-10-18 18:19:52.637',133,1)
     , (109,'2012-10-18 10:00:03.410','2012-10-18 10:19:52.637',133,-1)
     , (109,'2012-10-18 12:00:03.410','2012-10-18 12:20:52.637',133,-1)
     , (109,'2012-10-18 14:00:03.410','2012-10-18 14:20:08.677',133,-1)
     , (110,'2012-10-18 09:00:03.410','2012-10-18 15:19:52.637',31,1)

     SELECT EmpID
           , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), StartTime, 103) AS [Date] 
       , CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), StartTime, 108) AS [Time]
       , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), FinishTime, 103) AS Date_Off 
       , CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), FinishTime, 108) AS Time_Off
       , CASE WHEN IdleTime = -1 THEN '' 
     ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10)
           , DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND,StartTime,FinishTime),0), 108)END AS HHMMSS
      , CASE WHEN IdleTime = -1 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND,StartTime,FinishTime),0), 108)
    ELSE '' END AS TrainingTime
    FROM @Table
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server you are using 2005/2008/R2/2012?

Comment: What version of reporting services you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `#error` because you are trying to add varchars (blank/nulls) with integers.

Instead of blank or `NULL` make that `HH:MM:SS` column as 0:0:0 (or 00:00:00). If you don't want to show in the report you can hide it at the report level using the hide expression in textbox.  With this change SSRS will not need to mix varchars with numbers and you won't get #error.

Other way to handle this is handling it in SQL query itself.

```
SELECT EmpID, [Date], [Time],
CASE WHEN ColumnA = 'Training' THEN '00:00:00' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND,StartTime,FinishTime),0), 108) END AS HHMMSS
,
SUM(IIF (ColumnA='Training',0,DATEDIFF(SECOND, StartTime,FinishTime))) OVER  (PARTITION BY EmpID, [Date]) AS TotalTime
,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),
DATEADD(SECOND,
    SUM(IIF (ColumnA='Training',0,DATEDIFF(SECOND, StartTime,FinishTime))) OVER  (PARTITION BY EmpID, [Date])
, 108) AS TotalTimeHHMMSS
    FROM ....
    WHERE ....
```

Partition Columns depend on how you are partitioning the data based on `empid, jobid` and the other fields.
Now you have the total time in Seconds you can convert it either in SSRS or query.

Comment: Thanks @Anup Agrawal.
I tried: [SELECT CASE WHEN ColumnA = 'Training' THEN '00:00:00'
     ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND,StartTime,FinishTime),0), 108)
     END AS HHMMSS
  FROM TableA] and still getting error.

Comment: SELECT CASE WHEN ColumnA = 'Training' THEN 00:00:00
     ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND,StartTime,FinishTime),0), 108)
     END AS HHMMSS
  FROM TableA  will throw an error in SSMS

Comment: @dLight For the second comment you  forgot single quotes on 00:00:00. You need to use `'00:00:00'`

Comment: @dLight Also can you share your complete query for the dataset?

Comment: Hi @dLight I updated my answer with Query option, see if you can make that work. I added the group total in SQL query itself.

Comment: I updated my query with TotalTime and TotalTimeHHMMSS.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the Windowing function but getting error as DATEDIFF is not a Windowing Function.

Comment: I forgot the braces for IIF. I added the braces. Above code is not tested so you might need to tweak it to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks to @Anup and @Stanislovas Kalašnikovas. I changed from blank `''` to `'00:00:00'`in query field and after that I was able to use the first expression I posted and the one by @Stanislovas.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `IIF` statement in following:

```
=iif(IsNothing(Fields!HHMMSS.Value) OR Fields!HHMMSS.Value = "", "",
 CStr(sum(CInt(split(Fields!HHMMSS.Value,":")(0)))
 +sum(CInt(split(Fields!HHMMSS.Value,":")(1)))\60)
   &":"& CStr(sum(CInt(split(Fields!HHMMSS.Value,":")(1)))
  mod 60+sum(CInt(split(Fields!HHMMSS.Value,":")(2)))\60) 
  &":"& CStr(sum(CInt(split(Fields!HHMMSS.Value,":")(2))) mod 60)
)
```

**UPDATE**

```
=iif(Len(Fields!HHMMSS.Value) <= 0, "",
 CStr(sum(CInt(split(Fields!HHMMSS.Value,":")(0)))
 +sum(CInt(split(Fields!HHMMSS.Value,":")(1)))\60)
   &":"& CStr(sum(CInt(split(Fields!HHMMSS.Value,":")(1)))
  mod 60+sum(CInt(split(Fields!HHMMSS.Value,":")(2)))\60) 
  &":"& CStr(sum(CInt(split(Fields!HHMMSS.Value,":")(2))) mod 60)
)
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
=iif(Len(Fields!HHMMSS.Value) <= 0, "",
 CStr(sum(CInt(split(iif(Len(Fields!HHMMSS.Value) <= 0, "", Fields!HHMMSS.Value),":")(0)))
 +sum(CInt(split(iif(Len(Fields!HHMMSS.Value) <= 0, "", Fields!HHMMSS.Value),":")(1)))\60)
   &":"& CStr(sum(CInt(split(iif(Len(Fields!HHMMSS.Value) <= 0, "", Fields!HHMMSS.Value),":")(1)))
  mod 60+sum(CInt(split(iif(Len(Fields!HHMMSS.Value) <= 0, "", Fields!HHMMSS.Value),":")(2)))\60) 
  &":"& CStr(sum(CInt(split(iif(Len(Fields!HHMMSS.Value) <= 0, "", Fields!HHMMSS.Value),":")(2))) mod 60)
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and still getting error returned.

Comment: @dLight Check again, updated answer. If `UPDATE #1` not working, check `UPDATE #2`

Comment: Thank you Stanislovas. Sorry for the late reply. I tried the update and still could not get it to work. Could it be my query for `HHMMSS` field?  The query for the `HHMMSS` field is `  SELECT CASE WHEN ColumnA = 'Training' THEN ''
     ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND,StartTime,FinishTime),0), 108)
     END AS HHMMSS
  FROM TableA`